# Calling C random function in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, tasm

Can anyone please guide me on how to call functions of c in assembly. I am programming a snake game in tasm. now I have successfully programmed the moving part, I need to generate random values for the "food" of the snake. Can anyone please tell me how to call c rand() function in assembly. Would be a great help.

Comment: An easy way to figure it out is to write a little C program that calls `srand` and `rand` and compile it with the the compile flag that outputs the resulting assembly language. In short, parameters are pushed onto the stack in reverse order, and return code is provided in `eax` (or `ax` for 16-bit).

Comment: using the stack register.. hmm.. trying to implement it now. thanks

Comment: Cool. If you get really stuck, you can come back and post what you have for help. If you google "calling c from x86" you'll find some useful tidbits as well.

Comment: nevermind fellows..generated my own random number logic using some algorithms from previous random number generators and mixing it up.. It worked wonders :D.. Anyway, thank you everyone :)